# Page Control not changing when scroll view scrolls

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to add a page control to my scroll view, and have followed numerous web tutorials, the majority which use the same code as this [tutorial.](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/) However, once I place the code into my project, even with me making changes to the code to try to make it work, it just doesn't. I have managed to make the code work for when the page control is pressed, however it just won't work for the page scrolling. My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037416/scrollview-pagecontrol-dot-doesnt-change-with-the-page), although the answers are of no help. Here is my code:

MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
UIScrollView *svCollegeMain;
UIScrollView *svCollegePage;
UIPageControl *pcCollege;
UIView *viewP1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* svCollegeMain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* svCollegePage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl * pcCollege;
- (IBAction)changePage;

@end
```

and MainViewController.m

```
@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize svCollegeMain, svCollegePage, pcCollege;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.svCollegeMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 332);
self.svCollegePage.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
CGFloat pageWidth = 320;
int page = floor((svCollegeMain.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pcCollege.currentPage = page;
}

- (IBAction)changePage 
{
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.svCollegeMain.frame.size.width * self.pcCollege.currentPage;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.svCollegeMain.frame.size;
[self.svCollegeMain scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
self.svCollegeMain = nil;
self.svCollegePage = nil;
self.pcCollege = nil;
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Just incase this makes any difference, my view is set out with a view, then a main scroll view and page control within this view, another view and scroll view (next to each other) within the main scroll view, and finally a final view in the second scroll view (all in IB, did not want too much code), and everything is linked up in IB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that your MainViewController doesn't declare itself as implementing UIScrollViewDelegate, so I also assume that you've forgotten to set it up as the delegate for the scroll view in IB (otherwise it wouldn't compile).

Since it has no delegate defined, the scroll view won't be calling your scrollViewDidScroll function.

Tim

Comment: Thankyou SOOO Much!. That line flew right past me each time I checked the code. That and the following line were all it took: svCollegeMain.delegate = self; (.m) and the <UIScrollViewDelegate> in .h. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HeaderFile:

```
@interface DemoPageControlViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
BOOL pageControlUsed;
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
int  pageNumber;


}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageArray;


- (IBAction) changePage:(id)sender;
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "DemoPageControlViewController.h"

@implementation DemoPageControlViewController
@synthesize pageControl, scrollView, imageArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[imageArray addObject:@"small_one.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"small_two.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"small_three.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"small_four.png"];


// add the last image to first
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:       [imageArray objectAtIndex:([imageArray count] -1)]]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release]; 

for(int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width * i ) + 320   , 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
// add the first image to last
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * ([imageArray count]+1), 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release]; 

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * ([imageArray count]+ 2), self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO]; 
}

- (IBAction)changePage :(id)sender
{
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage ;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}


- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
pageControlUsed = NO;             
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
//pageControlUsed = NO;

NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.contentOffset.x);

CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
//pageNumber = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / ([imageArray count]+2)) / pageWidth) + 1  ;
pageNumber = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

if(pageNumber ==  0)
{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake((self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [imageArray count]), 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    pageNumber = [imageArray count];
    //self.pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
}
else if(pageNumber == ([imageArray count]+1))
{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    pageNumber = 1;
    //self.pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
}

self.pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber - 1;

  }

 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {

  }
```

This Code works fine. Try this